# Cisco DNAC - case insensitive search

Tags: cisco

Is there a way to do a case insensitive search using the Cisco DNA api?

Desired results: devices named “TEST”, “test”, “Test” etc

```
import request

url = "https:///dna/intent/api/v1/network-device?hostname=Test"

 payload = None

 headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

 response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers, data = payload)

 print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Documentation:  [Documentation>Cisco DNA Center Platform](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/dna-center/#!cisco-dna-center-2-3-3-api-api-devices-get-device-list)

Comment: Cross-posted here:  https://community.cisco.com/t5/cisco-digital-network-architecture-dna/dnac-api-trying-to-search-hostname-case-insensative/m-p/4807994

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

If there were a decent regex implementation, you could use a directive to make the match case insensitive (`(?i)hostname=Test`).

But most likely you'd need to use something like `hostname=[Tt][Ee][Ss][Tt]`.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion - the search continues.